# Get the Raw Request String from HttpServletRequest

Tags: java, jsf, servlets

Is it possible to get the raw HTTP Request from the HttpServletRequest object? I want to see the raw request as a String if at all possible.

I need to get the full text of the request, in this case it's a POST request, so the URL doesn't help. It's also part of a multi-part form, so I can't just call the "getParameterNames()" or "getParameterValues()".

Thank you,

Comment: What are the things you want to know about the request other than url

Comment: I have a custom JSF component. Inside of it's "decode()" method, I need to find out what elements were selected. On a form any other than multi-part, I can just call "getParameterValues('myparam')" and I can get the values (the list of items selected), but with a multi-part form that method doesn't return anything. So I need to manually parse the raw data to get the selected items. I can't use a servlet filter because it's only affecting my own custom component.

Comment: Turns out I figured out another way to get the parameters that I needed. If I use the FacesContext.getExternalContext.getParameterValuesMap() that gives me what I needed regardless of the form type.  Thanks to all

Comment: See this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36939915/2579281). In case of any query feel free to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you need a [servlet filter](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/Filter.html). There is no standard way to handle `multipart/form-data`, so you'll have to take care to cache this data appropriately when [wrapping the HttpServletRequest](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequestWrapper.html).

Comment: Note: this answer is no longer accurate. Servlet 3.0 (JEE6) introduced support for `multipart/form-data`. http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/annotation/MultipartConfig.html

Answer (score 12):

You can read the raw HTTP request by doing:

```
ServletInputStream in = request.getInputStream();
```

and then use the regular `read`methods of the InputStream.

Hope that helps.

Comment: This will only read the *body*, not the headers of the HTTP request.

Answer (score 4):

Well, it sounds like you are doing some sort of troubleshooting. Why not just drop the multi-part form component while you are looking at the raw form data. You can use the following JSP snippet to construct the form data.

```
<%
Enumeration en = request.getParameterNames();
String str = "";
while(en.hasMoreElements()){
   String paramName = (String)en.nextElement();
   String paramValue = request.getParameter(paramName);
   str = str + "&" + paramName + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(paramValue);
}
if (str.length()>0)
   str = str.substring(1);
%>
```

Answer (score 1):

or if you can write some interceptor to convert the parameter names and values to string format object and set it in request context, or filter is a good idea too.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the whole request to a String you can do it with one line of code using the apache IOUtils library.

```
String myString = org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toString(request.getInputStream());
```

Comment: Duplicate answer, better suited as a comment on that answer

Comment: @MarkJeronimus monchote's answer's is not accurate it doesn't get the input stream into a String as requested by Jaime

Comment: Firstly, it doesn't answer the question. With this you get the same result as with @monchote 's answer from 2010 - only body, no headers, no anything else. The question was about raw textual representation. Secondly, this IOUtils.toString(is) call is deprecated as of 2.5 version