# How to get posted xml from JAXRS MessageContext?

Tags: java, http, cxf, jax-rs

I am attempting to grab the XML from the MessageContext that JAXRS is passing in. Is there a way to get the contents of the XML directly from the methods contained in a MessageContext object?

I thought this would work:

```
@PUT
@Path ("/")
@Consumes ({ "application/json", "application/xml" })
@Produces ({ "text/html", "application/json", "application/xml" })
public Response update(@Context MessageContext mc) {
    mc.getHttpServletRequest().get....
    // unsure of how to grab the actual xml from the request...
```

But the information inside these is not what I am looking for. I just want the XML that is being pushed in the request.

There are options for logging interceptors, but I don't want to just log the request, I want to actually have the XML to do some manipulation on.

Answer (score 0):

You can use getRequest from the [api](http://cxf.apache.org/javadoc/latest/org/apache/cxf/jaxrs/ext/MessageContext.html). Then you just want to translate request to a string, as mentioned in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12260540/how-to-convert-an-httpservletrequest-to-string), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1342213/get-the-raw-request-string-from-httpservletrequest) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5023718/how-to-retreive-raw-post-data-from-httpservletrequest-in-java)

Comment: I have tried the bufferedreader, the inputstream, and the getParameter all seperately and they seem to be coming back null.

Comment: Or the message is empty, but it definitly shouldn't be at this point. Why else would I pass around the MessageContext?